# Why won't my css load?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I just got a domain and webhost with Godaddy and wanted to make my website one step closer to reality. It works well on my school server, but I copy and pasted my code, but the CSS won't load. The HTML and CSS are both in the public_html folder. I'm trying to link the stylesheet to my HTML page, but tried a URL to hopefully get it to link.  Here is my HTML:

```
<link  rel="stylesheet" href="http://csgosalt.com/style.css">
```

Also, this is my first question on this site, so tell me if I'm asking wrong.

PS I tried to put my whole CSS file into my style tag but it still didn't change anything.

Comment: You haven't presented nearly enough information for someone to provide a solution. Where is this html file located? Are you sure the css file is where it should be? How are you serving the css file? Is it being served by Apache or something else?

Comment: P.s this is what it is support to look like http://ito.auburncc.org/localuser/yr16/rwoessner/test2/

Answer (score 1):

Look at line 35 in style.css

```
html  
{

    background-image: url('@font-face { font-family: Csgo; src: url('csgo.ttf'); }
```

I don't know what you are trying to do here (perhaps a copy-paste error?) but this is what's breaking the rest of your CSS file.

Comment: Thank you i accidentally pasted twice

Answer (score -1):

you could add type="text/css" to the link

```
<link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://csgosalt.com/style.css">
```

but as the commenters say ... far too less information